# Appsync graphql connect to lambda keep returning null

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-appsync

I am new to appsync + lambda and setting up appsync + lambda graphql api deploy with [serverless framework](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-appsync-plugin), the lambda will return data from mysql, for now I am hardcoding the lambda return, to make sure no issue on lambda, actually Test lambda can get normal response, even with real database connection.

Seems the appsync cannot reach lambda function, as there is no log in cloudwatch, if I run the Test in lambda, there will be a log record in cloudwatch.

In AWS AppSync console schema

```
# ...

type Banner @aws_cognito_user_pools
@aws_api_key {
    title: String
}

type BannerList @aws_cognito_user_pools
@aws_api_key {
    banners: [Banner!]
    next_token: String
}

enum BannerType {
    WEB_MAIN
    # ...
}

type Query {
    listBanner(type: BannerType, limit: Int!, next_token: String): BannerList
        @aws_cognito_user_pools
@aws_api_key
}


# ...

schema {
    query: Query
}
```

reponse in appsync console Queries

```
{
  "data": {
    "listBanner": null
  }
}
```

Data Source setup with lambda function `listBanner`, and select role that have `lambda:invokeFunction` permission of Resource lambda `listBanner`

serverless.yml

```yaml
custom:
  appSync:
      dataSources:
        - type: AWS_LAMBDA
          name: LambdaListBanner
          description: ''
          config:
            functionName: listBanner

      mappingTemplates:
        - field: listBanner
          dataSource: LambdaListBanner
          type: Query
          request: false
          response: false
```

return response from lambda/ mysql